# Engine locked while driving

Tags: engine, engine-load

Hi I have a volvo 440 d13 motor. Driver could not get the truck started but dashboard displayed that it was in neutral and no faults appeared. A mechanic went to site and said that the truck was stuck in gear and after getting air into the gearbox he managed to get the truck started. Driver built up pressure and started driving. About 5km down the road the truck switched off while driving. We then opened up the I shift and got the truck in neutral but for some odd reason the truck won't start up again. We shorted the starter and could hear the starter engaging but the engine still refused to turn or swing. Mechanic said that the motor is locked. What will cause this?

Comment: Are you sure it really is in neutral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the engine is truly locked then there are a number of problems that might cause that.  Some that come to my mind are:

1. Lubrication problem caused one or more rod or crank bearings to seize.
2. Lubrication or overheating caused a piston to seize in the sleeve.
3. Valve breaks and jams the piston.
4. Excess fuel or oil into the cylinder causes hydrolock.
5. Broken connecting rod or crankshaft is blocking the engine rotation.
6. Cracked block causing misalignment of internal engine parts.

There are, of course, any number of other reasons but these seem to me to be among the most common.